# Doctrine2 Custom Repository result with multiple objects

Tags: doctrine-orm, ddd-repositories

i have the folllowing entities:

**User** 1:n **StatementResponse** n:1 **Statement** n:1 **Survey** 1:n **User**

As you can see, the relations between the entites are closed in a circle. I need to query all statements of a survey with the responses from a given user. Not every statement must be answered. The result should be an associative array which looks like that:

```
[
    1 => [
        'statement' => Statement Entity with id 1
        'response' => 'Response Entity from the given user of Statement with id 1
    ],
    2 => [
        'statement' => Statement Entity with id 2
        'response' => null 
    ],
    3 => [
        'statement' => Statement Entity with id 3
        'response' => Response Entity from the given user of Statement with id 3
    ]
]
```

Is it possible to get a result like this in a custom repository?

Comment: Pretty sure you will need two queries and then a merge.  Query all the statements for a given survey.  Then query all the responses for the statements for the given user.  Then build your array.  You might be able to do it on one shot.  Have you tried?